# Tests tab Run All total column value

Tags: unit-test, sandbox, developer-console

I did a 'Run All' for my tests from Sandbox Developer Console.

Under the tests tab, there is a column named `Total`. For my all tests it is shown as 8. In my org I have around 200 test methods which are spanned more than 8 files. My question is, is that number meaningful? Am I missing something in here?

[image]

Note that, for classes, I can see that it is the number of test methods that class has. I am asking for the number at the top.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you go deep into the minified Developer Console source the answers are hiding there.

As best I can tell, the "total" column is populated in the `processTestResults` function that is defined in /jslibrary/1539646802000/sfdc/ApexIDEPanels_Ext4.js. This is for loading the results into the testResultTree. The node we are interested in is the root node, which in my formatted source is `c`.

[image: Source of processTestResults]

Most of the child nodes get their Total from the `extstatus` returned by /_ui/common/apex/test/ApexTestQueueServlet?action=STATUS

Every time there is an update from the Streaming API the total for the root node is recalculated. However, it only appears to recalculate the total for the changing nodes.

I've found that if I close and then reopen the Developer Console after the tests have run it will update to the correct total, which should be the total number of test methods run.